# Vue app with WebStorm in mac npm ERR! missing script: dev

Tags: npm, vue.js, webstorm

I am trying to create a Vue App with WebStorm in Mac. When I run the   `npm run dev`  get this error:

> npm ERR! missing script: dev

This is my package.json:

```
"version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16"
  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because there's no `dev` script in your `package.json`. You should do `npm run serve`. The available scripts are the following

#### package.json

```
// ...
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve", // npm run serve
    "build": "vue-cli-service build", // npm run build
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"    // npm run lint
}, 
// ...
```

Comment: npm ERR! missing script: server

Comment: It's `serve`, not `server`

Comment: It's not missing. That is common on applications that needs a server. `server` is the noun, `serve` is the verb.